# Calculate net amount after discount in formula

Tags: sql-server-2008, formula, calculated-columns

I need to put value in calculated column in SQL Server.

The formula will need to be something like: col1 * 0.col2 (both columns 1&2 can be null). 
Col1 is the GrossAmount(decimal(10,2) and Col2(smallint) is the percent discount.

I tried to search for a solution on this, but found nothing helpful so far. Any idea where I might find a good solution for this?

Comment: This is pretty simple and straight-forward.  What part are you having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
select GrossAmount, DiscountPercentage,
  GrossAmount * DiscountPercentage / 100.0 as [DiscountAmount]
  from YourTable
```

This assumes that `DiscountPercentage` is the amount to be discounted in percent.  The discounted gross would then be:

```
GrossAmount * ( 100.0 - DiscountPercentage ) / 100.0 as [DiscountedGrossAmount]
```

In a table definition you could create a computed column thusly:

```
DiscountedGrossAmount as GrossAmount * ( 100.0 - DiscountPercentage ) / 100.0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
grossamount-(grossamount*(discountpercentage/100)) as Discountpercentage
```